# How to set parameters from console to own maven report plugin

Tags: maven, parameters, obfuscation

I have maven report plugin and I want to set parameters from console (-DparName=smth)
But I can't find how to do it. I need to set obfuscate (code below).

```
public class DsmReportMojo extends AbstractMavenReport {
        /**
         * 
         * @parameter default-value="true"
         * @required
         */
        private boolean obfuscate;

       //overriden methods

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which version of the maven-plugin-plugin version you are using:

maven-plugin-plugin 2.x:

```
@parameter expression="${aSystemProperty}" default-value="${anExpression}"
```

maven-plugin-plugin 3.x:

```
@parameter property="aSystemProperty" default-value="${anExpression}"
```

Comment: It doesn't work.
But thanks a lot. You pushed me to the solution:
`*@parameter expression="${obfuscate}" default-value="true"`